# SQL Server - Generate Dynamic JSon output

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following tables (pseudo names below) in SQL which I need to use to produce some dynamic JSON out from :

HeaderTable

```
RequestID int
RequestType varchar(50)
```

Sample Data

```
1 : User Name Change
2 : User Name Change
```

ValuesTable

```
RequestID int
Alias varchar(50)
FieldValue varchar(50)
```

Sample Data

```
1 : MobileNo : 07777777777
1 : Name : Fred Bloggs
2 : MobileNo : 07888888888
2 : Name : John Smith
```

The JSON I need to end up with is as follows :

```
[
{
    "request_type":"User Name Change",
    "request_details":[
        {
            "MobileNo":"07777777777",
            "Name":"Fred Bloggs"
        },
        {
            "MobileNo":"07888888888",
            "Name":"John Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

So I effectively need to pass my alias value as the key name in the JSON.

My code so far is as follows but I assume I might need some sort of dynamic SQL?

```
SELECT hdr.RequestType AS request_type
    , (
        SELECT vals.FieldValue  AS [request_details.value]
        FROM ValuesTable vals
        WHERE vals.RequestID = hdr.[RequestID]  
        FOR JSON PATH
      ) request_details
FROM HeaderTable hdr
FOR JSON PATH
```

I'm not sure if any of the other SQL JSON function might be useful here or if I need to somehow churn out some dynamic SQL as my only hope?

Comment: Do you know all possible values, stored in the `Alias` column or they can vary?

Comment: The values are all held in another table so I do know them, yes.

Comment: Are you sure about the sample data in the `ValuesTable`, especially the rows with `RequestID`  equal to `2` and this `WHERE vals.RequestID = hdr.[RequestID]` clause?

Comment: Yes sorry I had missed a header record - I want to lump all like request types together and have the values records make up the request_details lines

Comment: Please show that other table (columns and sample data), containing `Alias` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can build the required JSON directly (usinf `FOR JSON`), but you may try to build one part of the JSON output using basic string concatenation and aggregation.  Note, that starting for SQL Server 2016, you need to use `FOR XML PATH` for aggregation:

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO HeaderTable
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'User Name Change')
) v (RequestID, RequestType)

SELECT *
INTO ValuesTable
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'MobileNo', '07777777777'),
   (1, 'Name',  'Fred Bloggs'),
   (1, 'Address',  'Full address'),
   (2, 'MobileNo', '07888888888'),
   (2, 'Name', 'John Smith')
) v (RequestID, Alias, FieldValue)
```

Statement for SQL Server 2017:

```
SELECT 
   hdr.RequestType AS request_type, 
   JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT CONCAT(
         '[{',
         STRING_AGG(
            CONCAT(
               '"', 
               STRING_ESCAPE(vals.Alias, 'json'), 
               '":"', 
               STRING_ESCAPE(vals.FieldValue, 'json'), '"'
            ), 
            ','
         ),
         '}]'
      )   
      FROM ValuesTable vals
      WHERE vals.RequestID = hdr.[RequestID]
   )) AS request_details
FROM HeaderTable hdr
FOR JSON PATH
```

Statement for SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT 
   hdr.RequestType AS request_type, 
   JSON_QUERY(CONCAT(
      '[{',
      STUFF(
         (
         SELECT CONCAT(',"', vals.Alias, '":"', vals.FieldValue, '"') 
         FROM ValuesTable vals
         WHERE vals.RequestID = hdr.[RequestID]
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
         1, 1, ''
      ),
      '}]'
   )) AS request_details
FROM HeaderTable hdr
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "request_type":"User Name Change",
      "request_details":[
         {
            "MobileNo":"07777777777",
            "Name":"Fred Bloggs",
            "Address":"Full address"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Looks promising - we are on SQL Server 2016 (sorry should have said) so STRING_AGG not currently available?

Comment: @chilluk, for SQL Server 2016 you need to use `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: Thanks Zhorov awesome that seems to do what I want it to